# Casting to an optional value in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

When I wrote this:

```
// json is of type AnyObject
var status : String? = json.valueForKeyPath("status") as String?
```

Xcode seems to blocked in an infinite loop during the compilation:
[image: Xcode]

Is there something wrong in my code?

I've done some tests and when I wrote:

```
var status : String? = json.valueForKeyPath("status") as? String
```

Xcode is able to compile but what will be the behavior when `valueForKeyPath` will return `nil`.

Comment: What type is `json`? Why are you specifying `AnyObject `?

Comment: Consider that Swift is an early Beta, do expect it to have bugs.

Comment: I think your second effort is correct, and was going to verify in a playground but I can't get xcode6 to run for long enough to confirm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second version is correct. An optional value is supposed to be assigned to a statement that can return nil. This is the flow of that line:

1. valueForKeyPath returns an implicitly unwrapped optional of AnyObject (`AnyObject!`). This means that it can be nil or it can have a value.
2. An attempt is made to convert it to a `String`
3. If it is not possible to convert it to a `String`, return `nil` making `status` `nil`. If it is indeed a non-nil `String` return that making `status` whatever string is returned

Answer (score 6):

As the documentation says:

> *Because downcasting can fail, the type cast operator comes in two different forms. The optional form, as?, returns an optional value of the type you are trying to downcast to.*
>
> Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/au/jEUH0.l

This means that when you write `as? String`, the return value is automatically wrapped in an optional for you, so the actual type produced by this is `String?`, which is the behaviour that you want, so your second option is correct.

In your first example, you are trying to cast the value returned by `valueForKeyPath`, which is of type `AnyObject!` (`!` means *implicitly* unwrapped), to `String?`, which is *explicitly* wrapped, and this the value is not automatically wrapped in an optional for you, so, since these types are not identical, casting between them probably won't work.

**TL;DR**: your first option is actually incorrect (although it shouldn't crash the compiler, that's a bug), and your second option is correct and does what you want.